# ExtJS Time Comparison Returns NaN Using Cookies

Tags: extjs

I am creating a cookie that has the value of 2 hours later from now.

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set('JSONTime', Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.HOUR, +2));
```

Then I want to check if the current time is after the saved cookie time or not

```
alert(Ext.Date.diff(new Date(), Ext.util.Cookies.get('JSONTime'), Ext.Date.HOUR));
```

above returns NaN

```
alert(Ext.Date.getElapsed(new Date(), Ext.util.Cookies.get('JSONTime')));
```

above returns NaN too

I even tried to encode at the time when I save the time as a cookie then decode when I compare, still I get NaN results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone to know, I used getTime technique to deal with time comparison, I think afterall it's the most accurate way if all you need to do is compare two dates if one past or future.

I am setting the cookie time like this

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set('JSONTime', (Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.HOUR, +2).getTime()));
```

Then I compare the cookie like this

```
if (((new Date().getTime()) - (Ext.util.Cookies.get('JSONTime'))) > 0) {
            Ext.util.Cookies.clear('JSONTime');
        }
```

Essentially, if the result is negative it means the cookie is not expired yet if it means the positive cookie is expired because current time's timestamp is a higher value.